# Configure Stylus compilation to look for dependencies in another directory in WebStorm/IntelliJ IDEs

Tags: css, intellij-idea, webpack, webstorm, stylus

I have configured my IDE (*WebStorm*) to watch all my *Stylus files* and compile a *css* immediately using **File Watchers**.

So, if i have this structure:

```
styles
|-folder1
| └-file1.styl
└-folder2
  └-file2.styl
```

And if i want my file `file1.styl` to reference the styles of `file2.styl`, i do:

```
// File: file1.styl
@import '../folder2/file2'
```

My server handles it, compile everything and works without problems as expected. And my IDE made this easy autocompleting my dependencies paths, and compiling them to *css* showing me the final result. It actually make this:

```
styles
|-folder1
| └-file1.styl
|   └-file1.css
└-folder2
  └-file2.styl
    └-file2.css
```

So, everything works well at this point.

---

Now, in my architecture, i have this structure *working*:

```
styles
|-common
| └-commonfile.styl
|-folder1
| └-file1.styl
└-folder2
  └-file2.styl
```

In this way:

```
// File: file1.styl
@import 'commonfile'         // No relative path here.
@import '../folder2/file2'
```

So, `common` folder (or `commonfile.styl`) is now always accessible from any other *stylus file*, and *webpack* manage to solve it magically (Because i haven't access to it config file).

But, my IDE doesn't know that my files in `common` folder are accessible from the others files and think i'm wrong. And when it say to *Stylus* to try to compile `file1.styl`, *Stylus* say it **failed to locate @import file commonfile.styl**.

So, ¿How should i setup the *Stylus* **File Watcher** from *WebStorm* to make `commonfile.styl` referenceable from all *.styl files* in a way to compile them?

As an extra, ¿It's possible to make autocomplete function to work properly in this scenario too?

Or at least, ¿How WebPack is telling to Stylus to handle this scenario?

Comment: Not a Stylus user here, but: 1) Check your Stylus compiler command line parameters -- it should have a parameter where you can point to a folder where to lookup for such include files. For example `node-saas` (node.js version of Sass/SCSS compiler) has `--include-path` parameter; the same for LESS compiler.

Comment: 2) *"It's possible to make autocomplete function to work properly in this scenario too?"* Not sure about this .. but if IDE does not offer completion from that file yet .. then you may try marking parent folder of `commonfile.styl` as Resource Root (e.g. via content menu in project View panel or via `Settings/Preferences | Directories`) -- can help in resolving paths inside IDE. 3) *"How WebPack is telling to Stylus to handle this scenario?"* It must be trying few different (predefined?; common?) locations until it finds the file that is matched by name.